# Discord.js ReferenceError: channel is not defined while trying to test an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a discord bot and I was trying to test an embed and an error popped up saying

> ReferenceError: channel is not defined

This is the code for the embed

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(`[${message.author.tag}]: ${message.content}`);
  if (message.content === 'brh!testembed') {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setColor('#0099ff')
     .setTitle('Some title')
     .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
     .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
     .setDescription('Some description here')
     .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
     .addFields(
         { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
         { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
         { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
         { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
     )
     .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
     .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
      channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    
    }
});
```

Comment: You made a typo. Try `message.channel.send()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says you have not defined `channel` if you want to send the embed to the same channel as your command was used in just do:

```js
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

If you are using **v13** use:

```js
message.channel.send({embeds: [exampleEmbed]});
```